# React router click same link more than one times and browser back button

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React router example https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Lets try click the `about` link more than 1 times.

And then if i want to back to `home` page by the browser back button its need click more than 1 times to back to the `home` page.

How to avoid this issue? I am using `react-router` and `create-react-app`.

Comment: This is discussed [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5362) and [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3983). You can create your own component that wraps the `Link` that doesn't push a new entry to the history when the clicked `Link` is already active.

Comment: I found a info from there link, tried add `replace` like <Linkto={route.path} replace> but the history not push, i click back button will come back to the homepage even i click the link multi times.